# How i can change the Label for my Discussion Board App from "new discussion" to something else

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, development, discussion-board, script

I am working on SharePoint online 2013. and i add a new Discussion Board App inside my Team site collection.
now i name the new app as "News & Announcement", so i was expecting that the defualt link label to create new item will be changed from "new discussion" to "new news & announcements". but unfortunatly this is not the case. so now my App is labeled as "News & Announcements", while its create link is labeled as "new discussion". as follow:-

[image]

so now i tried writing the following script to override that label :-

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
var interval = setInterval(adjustlabel, 3000);

$('.ms-heroCommandLink span:last').text('New News & Announcments');

function adjustlabel() {
$('.ms-heroCommandLink span:last').text('New News & Announcments');

    }
});
</script>
```

here is the markup for the link (as shown inside firefox )

[image]

*side note i provide a timer because user can chose to reload the view (ajax-based request).*
Now the above script did not work , but when i edit my page i have noted that the link got the new label, but if i save my Page, the label will return back to "new discussion" ! 
so can anyone adivce on this please? why the script worked only when the page is on edit mode??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at render function within sp.ui.discussion.debug.js. You'd find two strings: Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkAltText and Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkFormat. You can override these string variables and use JSLink's postRender method or use the code below inside a Script Editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//self-executing anonymous function
(function () {
    // String overrides
    function DiscussionListViewStringOverride() {
        Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkAltText = "add new News & Announcements";
        Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkFormat = "New News & Announcements";
    }

    DiscussionListViewStringOverride();
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(DiscussionListViewStringOverride, "strings.js");
})();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added a script editor web part to my page, with the following code `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s*****/Style%20Library/jquery-1.10.2.js">
</script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkAltText = "add new News & Announcments"
Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkFormat = "New News & Announcments";
});
</script>` but it did not change the title, never inside the edit mode nor inside the read mode.. atleast inside my script the title will be change on the edit mode.can u adivce further please?

Comment: Add it without the dom ready. It should work.

Comment: ok the later code worked fine, but can you adivce why the first code (with dom ready) did not work ?? second point, now if i do a refresh (ajax based refresh) for the web part which is showing the Discussion board , the label will return back to be "new discussion",, so should i add a timer to re-execute the script each N seconds ??

Comment: can you adivce more on my above comment?thanks

Comment: see the updated answer. DOM ready didn't work - I think it has do with the sequence of javascript files being loaded particularly strings.js. Better solution would be to apply JSLink prerender and postRender methods but as soon you apply JSLink to this view, things break.

Comment: and what about re-executing the script inside a timer, because if i do an ajax update for the web part ,, then the link label will change back to "new discussion".. so i need to re-execute the script after the DOM is being updated with an ajax request..can u advice on this please?

Comment: did you try the updated script for ajax refresh,?

Comment: thanks a lot it worked well. now i will accept the answer since it covers what i am looking for.b but have 2 question if you can advice on; 1) can you provide me with some links which talks about the approach you used ? 2) usually i use .css files to do such customization, but the problem with .css , is that i need to hard code the related css class names (where these classes might get new names after applying CU) ,, so should i always consider your appraoch over defining custom css rules???

Comment: this has nothing to do with CSS, wrong post?

Comment: yes i am not asking about css,, i am saying that your appraoch is better than trying to achieve similar things using css.. but i am asking you about the name of the technique you used inside the javaScript to achieve this , is it JSOM, user custom action ,etc... ?? so i can read more about it